# Error: Renderer already associated with window

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I am trying to set up an SDL project, however I am getting from following error message:

```
Renderer already associated with window
```

from the following function:

```
void Game::render()
    {
        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
        if (renderer == NULL)
            std::cout << "Failed to create a renderer" << '\n' << "Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }
```

I have only made a window and a renderer once, and they are separate, so I have no idea why this could happen. I found another question on SO with the same error, but apparently he was having problems because `SDL_GetWindowSurface()` was being called but I am not calling that function. The following is my code. Thanks for helping.

`game.h:`

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"

class Game
{
public:

    bool init();
    bool constructWindow
    (
        const char* windowName,
        unsigned int xWindowPos,
        unsigned int yWindowPos,
        unsigned int windowWidth,
        unsigned int windowHeight,
        bool fullScreen = false
    );

    void render();
    void update();
    SDL_Window* getWindow();
    bool handleEvents();

protected:


private:
    SDL_Window* window = nullptr;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = nullptr;
    SDL_Event event;
    bool quit = false;

};
```

`game.cpp:`

```
    #include "game.h"
    
    bool Game::init()
    {
        if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0)
            return true;
        else
            std::cout << "Could not initialise SDL" << '\n' << "Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }
    
    bool Game::constructWindow(const char* windowName, uint16_t xWindowPos, uint16_t yWindowPos
        , uint16_t windowWidth, uint16_t windowHeight, bool fullScreen)
    {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow(windowName, xWindowPos, yWindowPos, windowWidth, windowHeight, fullScreen);
        if (!window)
            std::cout << "Could not create window" << '\n' << "Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    
        return window;
    }
    
    void Game::render()
    {
        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
        if (!renderer)
            std::cout << "Failed to create a renderer" << '\n' << "Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }
    
    void Game::update()
    {
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
    
    SDL_Window* Game::getWindow()
    {
        return window;
    }
    
    bool Game::handleEvents()
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                quit = true;
        return quit;
    }
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "game.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Game app;
    if (app.init())
        if (app.constructWindow("3D Engine", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1200, 600))
            while (!app.handleEvents())
            {
                app.render();
                app.update();
            }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(app.getWindow());
    SDL_Quit();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: Calling `app.render()` (that creates renderer, despite misleading name) in a `while` loop is definitely not "creating renderer once". You probably should create renderer in `constructWindow` and do actual rendering in `render` instead.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't notice that. It works now, thanks

Comment: I did as you suggested, changed the name of the function to `constructWindowAndRenderer` and left `render` function only to actually draw stuff.